# warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to compile the below code using GCC compiler

```
class Class
{
public:

uInt16    temp;
const uInt32 function() const;

}

inline const uInt32 class::function() const
{
   return temp;
}
```

And I'm getting the following compiler warning

> warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]

Any ideas how I can fix this warning?

Comment: What type is `uInt32`?

Comment: I don't think you need a class to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Use simply:

```
uInt32 function() const;
```

Returning const primitive type is useless, as you cannot do `c.function()++` even without `const`.

Returning const Object was used to mimic primitives and forbid code similar to above,
but now (since C++11), we can forbid that cleanly, if required:

```
struct S
{
    S& operator ++() &;
    S& operator ++() && = delete;
};

S f(); // Sufficient, no need of const S f() which forbids move
```

Comment: Your explanation is **great!**

Answer (score 3):

The `const` type qualifier on the return type has no effect. Indeed, your `function` returns a copy of `temp`. It's the caller who will decide whether this value has to be const or not:

```
const auto val = Class{}.function(); // here, val is const
auto val = Class{}.function(); // here val is not const
```

The `const` type qualifier makes sense if, for example, you want to return a reference to a class member. Compare:

```
int f() { /* ... */ } // return int
const int& f() { /* ... */ } // return const reference to an int
```